# What's the max number allowed as nonce?

Tags: web3js, infura, nonce, web3js-v1.x, web3js-v0.x

I tried to generate nonce using this formula, so I can avoid 'underpriced' problem and nonce conflicts

```
nonce: web3.utils.toHex( Math.round (Date.now() / 1000 - 1586000000)  ),
```

But simply these transactions are been refused ( I am using Infura rpc)

Why?

Actually it generates number like `365158`. Not so great I think...

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to getTransactionCount for nonce calculation, it was just an idea for cases when sending 2 or more transaction in a minute and so old ones are note mined. Just a curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nonces must be processed in order (i.e. 0, 1, 2, ...).

Your formula will not achieve this order and your transactions will be ignored.